# Convert a value as a result of google colab which has e to a real value?

Tags: python, math, google-colaboratory

I have something like 3.34985746e-06  as a result of a calculation in colab. How can I convert this to a more readable value?

Comment: What makes that value not real?

Comment: @Chrispresso more readable

Comment: What is more readable for you though? To me scientific notation is way more readable than `0.00000334985756`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just confused why it's represented as a string you can get it back to a float using `float()`.

```py
In [11]: val = '{:e}'.format(12312312312123)

In [12]: val
Out[12]: '1.231231e+13'

In [13]: float(val)
Out[13]: 12312310000000.0
```

If instead you want fewer decimals displayed you can format your scientific notation with `{:.Ne}` where N is the number of decimals places:

```
In [14]: '{:.3e}'.format(0.00000334985756)
Out[14]: '3.350e-06'
```

Notice that the above also takes care of rounding for you.